# Picture lens doesn't find anything

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I get Facebook results, but nothing from my computer.

If I open a terminal and use 'locate' then I can find stuff, but the picture lens is empty.

Note that my picture files are on an NTFS partition. I have made a link named 'Pictures' in my home folder that points to the location where the picture files are. Again, this works with the 'locate' command and it also works for the Music lens, which is also a link in my home folder.

It also (kinda) works for the Video lens, though it only wants to find videos I have opened, which seems not consistent with the other lenses. (and also not very useful this way)

Answer (score 1):

Pictures and video lenses only search the picture and video folders when searching local filesystems.

It's my understanding they don't follow symlinks same as UbuntuOne <-- could be mistaken on the prior.

Comment: It is a local filesystem though, not some network drive. Would there be a better way to indicate to Unity where my picture files are?  A symlink to my documents partition works well enough for Nautilus and most lenses, just not the Pictures lens.

Comment: Yes, but they don't follow symlinks.  It's a logic free way of preventing trying to recursively search a circular link tree.